# boilerplate 4.0 - JavaScript function is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using Boilerplate 4.0 with main.js being loaded at the bottom of the body tag. I am trying to write the footer as script to make updating the copyright year easier, i.e. in main.js vs every html file. The function reference in the html comes before main.js is loaded, so I keep getting:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined"

I can load main.js before the footer section and everything works, but doesn't that defeat the purpose?

html code:

```
<footer id="page-footer">
    <script src="js/footer.js"></script>
        <h5>
        <script>footera();</script>
        <strong><a href="main.html"><script>footerb();</script></a></strong>
        <script>footerc();</script>
        </h5>
</footer>
```

main.js code:

```
 function footera() {
        document.write("Copyright&copy; 2012, "); 
    }
   function footerb() {
    document.write("<name>, "); 
    }
    function footerc() {
        document.write("all rights reserved"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call a javascript function before the browser has created that function, you will get an error. So calling the script before you use the functions is the right way.

However, I wouldn't use document.write anyway. I would change the code of the tags. If you use querySelectors instead, you will actually want to put it at the very bottom.

```js
let footertitle = document.querySelector(".footer-title");
let footerlink = document.querySelector(".footer-link");
let footersubtitle = document.querySelector(".footer-subtitle");

footertitle.innerHTML = "Copyright &copy; 2012, ";
footerlink.innerHTML = ",";
footersubtitle.innerHTML = " all rights reserved";
```

```css
.footer-link{font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<footer id="page-footer">
  <h5>
    <span class="footer-title"></span>
    <a class="footer-link" href="main.html"></a>
    <span class="footer-subtitle"></span>
  </h5>
</footer>
```